# Angular Lifecycle Hook that Detects Cookie Changes

Tags: angular, cookies

I have an Angular 5 application that stores some information in a cookie. I would like to use the Lifecycle Hooks to detect when the cookie expires and run some code after it does. I have already tried using `OnChanges` and `AfterContentInit` but to no avail.

Does anyone know if realtime detection of changes to a cookie can be done with Angular's Lifecycle Hooks? Or if there is another method of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the Lifecycle Hooks you're talking abouts are hooks on Angular elements like components, so no with those you cannot detect when one of you cookie is expired.

If I were you, I would try to check my cookie like everytime I'm moving in my app with the Angular Router for example. Something like that in your components :

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.events
     .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
     .subscribe(_ => // Get your cookie and check it);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did think that the Lifecycle Hooks would probably not be able to help, but asked about them in case I was wrong. Your solution is great, but would it be possible to achieve this without checking on every route change?

Comment: I figured out a better way! I have a header that must appear on every page (template) at the top. I just perform the check you described there and it works on every route change. Thanks again for your solution!